# Is it possible that paper accepted in IEEE Financially Sponsored conference later not included in IEEE Explore scopus conference proceedings?

Tags: conference, ieee, proceedings

One of my paper was accepted at a financially sponsored IEEE conference which is listed on the IEEE upcoming conference page.  The reviewer comments were positive and the paper got accepted. Now after 2 days, one of the conference organizers is saying that my paper may later be excluded by the IEEE as it may not be in scope. Is this possible ? Why was the paper accepted in the first place then?

I thought only papers which have not been presented/absenteesim can be exlcuded from conference proceeding's